# Django: URL not recognized? Have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Tags: python, django

So I'm making an episode tracker for tv shows, currently making the "Add show" form. When I go to localhost:8000/add, it says that that is not found. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

**views.py**

```
class ShowCreate(CreateView):
    model = Show
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'episode', 'season']
```

**index.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'show:show-add' %}">Add</a>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^add/$', views.ShowCreate.as_view(), name='show-add'),
```

**show_form.html**

```
{% extends 'show/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Add Show{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 

<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<h1>Add show</h1>
{% include 'show/form-template.html' %}
<button>Submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**form_template.html**

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form">
    <h3>{{field.label_tag}}</h3>
    <div class="field">{{field}}</div>
</div><!--form-->
{% endfor %}
```

This is everything in urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [

  # index
  url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

  # show detail
  url(r'^(?P<show>[\w.@+-]+)/$', views.ShowDetail.as_view(), name='show-detail'),

  # form to add show
  url(r'^add/$', views.ShowCreate.as_view(), name='show-add'),

  # delete show

  # signup

  # login

  # logout

]
```

Error message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/add/
Raised by:  show.views.ShowDetail
```

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('show.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Please show the rest of the URLs, as well as how they are being included from the main urls.py.

Comment: Did you rerun your django calls to set them up?

Comment: can you share the error screen you get with debug=True in settings.py?

Comment: @Fallenreaper what do you mean?

Comment: `add/` also matches the pattern for ShowDetail above it, and that show probably doesn't exist. Switch the order of pthe patterns.

Comment: Edited to add new code!

Comment: @RemcoGerlich it was that simple... Thanks. Oh my god. I spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: That the error was raised by show.views.ShowDetail should have been a hint :-) Glad to have helped